# Firebase notification details at time of application in the background

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase-notifications

how to get Firebase notification details at time of application in the background and handle the intent at the time of application in the background then notification are come then click

Comment: Are you aware of pendingintent being passed in notification?

Comment: yes, I aware of pending intent and .setContentIntent(pendingIntent) are already pass. but the time of application is run in the background then notification is come then click at notification can't redirect provided intent.

Comment: please share the implementation of notification and pending intent

Comment: PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new 
                 NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),
                channel_id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_logo)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000,
                        1000, 1000})
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);